# JWindow Inject in Desktop

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

Can anyone show example on how to make a `JWindow` always on Desktop?
I cannot set the "AlwaysOnTop" since I do not want it to be on top of other applications, but I want it to stay on Desktop.

Whenever I click the show Desktop button or Windows Key + M to minimize all, it disappears also. When i return to any window, it will be visible again.

I wanted to inject the window in the desktop.

Comment: What is so special about this app. that the user would want it **always** on screen?

Comment: app is for monitoring of exchange rates, I want it always on screen and update values every nth seconds

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want to prevent user from minimizing your app window?

Comment: I already tried setAlwaysonTop but it is not what I wanted to. There is no code which injects the JWindow in desktop. JWindow cannot be minimized but for some reason, when I click windowskey + m (shortcut to show windows desktop) the JWindow is minimized.. I want it to stay on desktop.

Comment: *"update values every nth seconds"* Yeah whatever. The point is, the **user** is capable of recognising when they do **& don't** want to watch those numbers fluctuating. So none of what you are trying to do makes sense. *"I want.."* You're just the programmer. What you want is irrelevant.

Comment: hmmm.. i am the one who will use the application, it is for myself, i cant find anything that can do what i think so im trying to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what do you mean by *"I wanted to inject the window in the desktop."* but if you want to prevent your application window from being minimized (`ICONIFIED`), you can write a small `WindowStateListener` and in the `windowStateChanged` check for the new state of your window. If its new state was `ICONIFIED` you can change the state to `NORMAL` again:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getNewState());
            if(e.getNewState() == JFrame.ICONIFIED) {
                jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    });
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

It will support your <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> hot key, because after minimizing all windows, your application's window will be deiconified.

Hope this help.

Comment: hi, what i mean is to make it permanent in desktop, if you know rainmeter, like that one, even though windows + m hot key is pressed, it does not disappear. i tried the code above, it still got minimized but the icon on the task bar is glowing.

Comment: Making something built-in into desktop is beyond the abilities of a Window because a window has a definition different than what you want. You need something like a Gadget. But about the code above, I tested it against two version of windows (7 and 10) and it's working. After minimizing it gets into the `NORMAL` state again.